# How to parse parameters in a URL Fragment using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, url, urllib

I need to parse a large number of URLs to retrieve a guid using urllib/python3.  Some urls contain a fragment which causes problems with returning the parameters.

```
import urllib

url = "https://zzz.com/index.html#viewer?guid=6a755e6d-4eae&Link=true&psession=true")
parse_response = urllib.parse.urlsplit(self.url)
self.logger.info("The parsed url components = {}".format(parse_response))
```

> The parsed url components = SplitResult(scheme='https', netloc='abc.com', path='/index.html', query='', fragment='viewer?guid=6a755e6d-4eae&Link=true&psession=true')]

So urllib rightly sees the "#" and stores the rest of the URL as a fragment, and will not return the parameters.  What is the best way to process the URL's with and without fragments?

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urldefrag, parse_qs
url = " https://abc.xyz.com/url/with/fragment/query#param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3"

print(urlparse(url))
print(urlparse(url).fragment)

pq = parse_qs(urlparse(url).fragment)
print(pq)
print(type(pq))
print("Using urlparse {}".format((pq["access_token"][0])))


f = urldefrag(url).fragment
print(type(f))
print(f)

pq = parse_qs(f)
print(pq)
print(type(pq))
print("Using urldefrag {}".format((pq["access_token"][0])))
```

Comment: According to RFC [3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3), the fragment starts after the `#` character, so in your example, `param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3` is the fragment. `parse_qs` and `parse_qsl` were made to parse the query, not the fragment. Your code works for an URI like `http://localhost#param1=value1&param2=value1`, but fails with `http://localhost#param1&value1.`